# How I can transform a jQuery function in one AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, directive, no-duplicates

I have to validate a form with a directive, for to AngularJS can to be able to enable or disable the submit form button.

I have a function in jQuery, but I need that AngularJS watches this behavior.

This function compares inputs to prevent duplicate information in each one.

```
<form id="myform">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="currency1" class="required" unique="currency"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="currency2" class="required" unique="currency"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="currency3" class="required" unique="currency"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="currency4" class="required" unique="currency"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the function

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("unique", function(value, element, params) {
     var prefix = params;
     var selector = jQuery.validator.format("[name!='{0}'][name^='{1}'][unique='{1}']", element.name, prefix);
     var matches = new Array();
     $(selector).each(function(index, item) {
         if (value == $(item).val()) {
             matches.push(item);
         }
     });

     return matches.length == 0;
          }, 
       "Valor Repetido"
     );


     jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.unique = {
          unique: true
     };

     $("#myform").validate();

     $("#validate").onBlur(function() {
          $("#myform").valid();
     });
```

and CSS

```
label.error { color: red }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: could you please tell me what are you validating  using jquery. I thought inputs of user Am I right or wrong ..?

Comment: this form validates a lot of products that are part of a package and these products cannot repeat themselves in the same package

Answer (score 1):

You can have an object array to hold all of the values, and deep watch that.
In controller:

```
$scope.currencies =
    [{'value':'val1'},{'value':'val2'},{'value':'val1'} ];

$scope.$watch('currencies', function(){
    $scope.duplicates = false;
    var found = [];
    $scope.currencies.forEach(function(currency){
        if(!(found.indexOf(currency.value)+1))
            found.push(currency.value);
        else $scope.duplicates = true;
    });
},true); //The 'true' last parameter is the signal to deep watch.
```

Each input in your table is bound with `ng-model` to an object in `$scope.currencies` so that the deep watch will see any changes immediately. You can generate the list of inputs using the `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<tr ng-repeat="currency in currencies">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="currency.value"></input></td>
</tr>
```

Then for the submit button, have `<input type="submit" ng-disabled="duplicates"></input>`

If you wanted to, you could then add buttons to add or remove elements from `$scope.currencies`, and it would immediately be reflected in the view.

[Plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/yxXkhgnLIU2fy8Pj9rF8?p=preview)

Comment: so, how I can to put every input into $scope.currencies?
by name="currency1"
by id=
or by class=""
I don't understand it...

Comment: You'll be using the ng-model attribute to bind your inputs to your JS variables. When one updates, the other will automatically. I've updated the answer a bit to make it more obvious.

Comment: I did run this code, but no matter what I put in each input,
the submit button always stands disabled

Comment: I've made a correction in my example, and have included a working Plunker example.

Comment: thank you so much
can you help me to find more examples about custom directives just to practice more?
thank you again

Comment: The most obvious place I can think of is the CodeSchool course linked to on the AngularJS website-
http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js

Comment: would be possible to highlight every 'input' that's repeat at moment when 'duplicate' is true?